# Dividing region in 9 sub-regions in Google Earth Engine

Tags: polygon, google-earth-engine, geometry

I am studying the spectral response of PV plants in GEE. I need to divide a polygon (geometry), which is shaped like the plant, in 9 sub-polygons, to investigate how each corner of the plant reacts.

Is there any way I could not do it by hand, and let GEE do it?